# React Native "Camera.Constants.Type" gives error

Tags: reactjs, types, camera, native

If i include this two lines then it shows error.
It says "undefined is not an object"
How can i fix this?[image: App Screen on Android Emulator]

```js
const frontCamera = Camera.Constants.Type.front
const backCamera = Camera.Constants.Type.back
```

Comment: Maybe your import of `Camera` is incorrect? Try `console.log(Camera)`.

Comment: i use this "import Camera from 'react-native-camera';"

Comment: What is the output of the console log I suggested above?